# Convert h:min:sec:milliseconds to minutes:seconds in R

Tags: r

I have performance data for each person `(ID)` over time, that is imported into R as a factor. An example is:

```
head(df, 4)
    TimeStart     TimeFinish    ID                  
1   0:00:00:08    0:00:12:06    1          
2   0:05:35:02    0:05:55:05    1      
3   0:13:33:01    0:13:53:03    2     
4   0:19:26:02    0:19:46:08    2 

> sapply(df, class)
  TimeStart  TimeFinish     ID       
"factor"    "factor"    "factor"
```

I wish to have `TimeStart` and `TimeFinish` as numeric in minutes.seconds format. The millisecond precision is not needed. The hours are also not required. I would like the data in numeric format for plotting. My desired output would be:

```
 head(df, 4)
    TimeStart     TimeFinish    ID                  
1   0.0           0.12          1          
2   5.35          5.55          1      
3   13.33         13.53         2     
4   19.26         19.46         2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what are the classes of TimeStart and TimeFinish? please use `sapply(df, class)` and post its output in the question

Comment: What about the hour part?  Is it all 0's?

Comment: The hours are not required (question is updated). It is all 0's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we need only a string transformation.  Loop through the columns of interest, use `gsub` to remove the hour and milli seconds part, replace the `:` with `.` and convert to `numeric`

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) 
       as.numeric(sub(":", ".", gsub("^[^:]+:|:[^:]+$", "", x))))
df
#  TimeStart TimeFinish ID
#1      0.00       0.12  1
#2      5.35       5.55  1
#3     13.33      13.53  2
#4     19.26      19.46  2
```

Comment: Does the second substitution need to be global? Surely `sub` would be fine.

Comment: @NickKennedy  I used `sub` as there was only a single `:` case.  Even `chartr` may also work.  Thank you.  Haven't see you for a while.  You provided some great answers which I still remember

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I've been busy with other things! I'd overlooked the `|` in the middle of the regex on a casual parse, and so had seen a regex that seemed to span the entire length of the input and therefore couldn't match more than once. I can see now why it needs to be `gsub`. Incidentally, `as.numeric(sub("^\\d+:(\\d+):(\\d+):\\d+$", "\\1.\\2", x)))` is slightly more typing but achieves the regex substitution using a single pass.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `lapply`. We convert the factor format of time into `POSIXct` class and extract only the minute and second part of it with `format` and then convert it into numeric.

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) 
                as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(x, format = "%H:%M:%OS"), "%M.%S")))

df
#  TimeStart TimeFinish ID
#1      0.00       0.12  1
#2      5.35       5.55  1
#3     13.33      13.53  2
#4     19.26      19.46  2
```

Answer (score 1):

split strings by ":" using `strsplit` and loop through its output and collapse 2nd and 3rd elements by "." using `paste()` and assign it back to `df` data frame.

```
df[, 1:2] <- lapply(df[, 1:2], function( x){
  lapply( strsplit( as.character(x), ":" ), function( x ) paste( x[2:3], collapse = "." ))
} )
#   TimeStart TimeFinish ID
# 1     00.00      00.12  1
# 2     05.35      05.55  1
# 3     13.33      13.53  2
# 4     19.26      19.46  2
```